# Return the value from a range that matches with another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have something like this:

[image]

From `A8:A10` I have a list with few companies; maybe more, maybe less, perhaps different from the ones in `A2:A4`. How can I get in `B8` the value from C if there is a company in `A2:A4` called the same as `A8`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about a simple [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en):

```
=VLOOKUP(A8,$A$2:$B$4,2)
```

[image]

or if you want the value in C:

```
=VLOOKUP(A8,$A$2:$C$4,3)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Mario, thanks for the speed and answer. I was trying that but it wasn't working. I rechecked after your answer and I just realized I was using it wrong; the range I was using was shorter than what I was asking to return. Instead of `=VLOOKUP(A8,A2:C4,3)` I was using `A8,A2:A4,3`. Sorry for your patience!